# How to set file encoding to ISO-8859-1 or WinCP-1252 in C++

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8, locale

I am learning C++ and I have a requirement to write a CSV file encoded in ISO-8859-1 or WinCP-1252.

I've tried the following code snippet to set a locale that will use 1252 codepage encoding, but when I open the output file in Notepad.exe, the encoding is displayed as UTF-8.

```cpp
std::ofstream ofs;
ofs.imbue(std::locale("English_United States.1252"));
ofs.open("file.txt");
ofs << 78123.456 << std::endl;
```

Comment: Most encodings (including ISO-8859-1, Win1252, and UTF-8) handle basic ASCII characters using the exact same bytes. So, you are not going to see any difference between encodings until you deal with non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you use only chars with ASCII codes 0..127, you should not care of a file encoding. UTF-8 is a default Notepad encoding, 8-bit multibyte. Notepad is not a tool for determining a file encoding. In other words, chars with ASCII codes 0..127 can be considered to be any 8-bit ISO or multibyte encoding.